# Flutter app with FCM doesn't open a specific route

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications to my Flutter app. But it doesn't open a specific route, it only opens the main page.

In my `AndroidManifest` I added :

```
<action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

And in the firebase console I add this:
[FirebaseConsoleSnippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pUky.png)

this is my code to receive notification and handle the click:

```
 class PushNotificationService {
  final FirebaseMessaging _fcm;
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigationKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> get navigationKey => _navigationKey;
  PushNotificationService(this._fcm);

  Future initialise() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
    }
    
    String token = await _fcm.getToken();
    debugPrint("FirebaseMessaging token: $token");
    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        debugPrint("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        debugPrint("onLaunch: $message");
        _serialiseAndNavigate(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        debugPrint("onResume: $message");
        _serialiseAndNavigate(message);
      },
    );
  }

  void _serialiseAndNavigate(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    var notificationData = message['data'];
    var view = notificationData['view'];
    debugPrint('view: ${view.toString()}');
    if (view != null) {
      if (view == "events") {
        navigationKey.currentState.pushNamed('/events');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my console output: [ConsoleOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ8az.png)

In my main file I declared the route like this:

```
routes: {
 '/events': (BuildContext context) => EventsScreen(),
}
```

Can you help me find the problem? If you need more info please feel free to ask!